# Cat headers and renaming a column header using awk?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I've got an input file (input.txt) like this:

```
name value1 value2
A 3 1
B 7 4
C 2 9
E 5 2
```

And another file with a list of names (names.txt) like so:

```
B
C
```

Using grep -f, I can get all the lines with names "B" and "C"

grep -wFf names.txt input.txt

to get

```
B 7 4
C 2 9
```

However, I want to keep the header at the top of the output file, and also rename the column name "name" with "ID". And using grep, to keep the rows with names B and C, the output should be:

```
**ID** value1 value2
B 7 4
C 2 9
```

I'm thinking awk should be able to accomplish this, but being new to awk I'm not sure how to approach this. Help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it is certainly possible to do this in `awk`, the fastest way to solve your actual problem is to simply prepend the header you want in front of the grep output.

```
echo **ID** value1 value2 > Output.txt && grep -wFf names.txt input.txt >> Output.txt
```

**Update** Since the OP has multiple files, we can modify the above line to pull the first line out of the input file instead.

```
head -n 1 input.txt | sed 's/name/ID/' > Output.txt && grep -wFf names.txt input.txt >> Output.txt
```

Comment: Thanks. It does work for one file, but I have many files; the column names value1 and value2 is different for each file, so I can't really just prepend a predefined header..

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to do it with `awk`

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$1];next} FNR==1 {$1="ID";print} {for (i in a) if ($1==i) print}' name input
ID value1 value2
B 7 4
C 2 9
```

Store the `names` in an array `a`
Then test filed `#1` if it contains data in array `a`